# How wget in linux can show content as window

Tags: wget

I am using wget to show html content.
In window, can show the content

[image]

In linux, it can not show:

[image]

Are there anys way to show all content in Linux

Comment: try -d for debug info or -v for verbose output.

Comment: Sorry, it can not work.

Comment: your next best bet is to read through the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Overview)

Answer (score 0):

You might inform GNU `wget` to output content to standard output (rather than file), but keep in mind you will see file as-is, that is it will not render HTML, consider that

```
wget -O - http://www.example.com
```

gives output, which contains

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        
    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```